# Java String - include part hidden by 'offset'

Tags: java, string

I have a Java String object with the value: "c:SAMPLE". 
Its offset=2 and count=6 so the actual string is "SAMPLE".

How can i build a new String that will be equal to "c:SAMPLE"?

Comment: I'm confused - show us your code. The offset/count stuff are typically arguments to a `String` constructor, so if you already have a string with a value of `"c:SAMPLE"`, you would only have to copy that string.

Answer (score 5):

The `count` and `offset` fields are private to the String. You probably saw them using a debugger. It just means that the String you're seeing is a substring of some other String, which existed before.

If you want the original String, find where the substring operation has been called, and store the original String somewhere. The fact that a substring is implemented by sharing the same array as its original String is just an implementation detail, used to optimize memory usage. You can't use it as a way to recover the original String.

If you're referring to the offset and count arguments of the String constructor, they're just used to extract only some part of the char array passed as argument. Once the copy of the chars from the array is done, the count and offset are forgotten. They're not part of the String.